# How to print the value selected in a drop-down box in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a web page which goes like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bug UI</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    function myfunc()
    {
    //what goes here??
    }
</script>
<form>
    <select name = "parameters">
        <option value = "param1">Param 1</option>
        <option value = "param2">Param 2</option>
        <option value = "param3">Param 3</option>
        <option value = "param4">Param 4</option>
        <option value = "param5">Param 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "myfunc()" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays a drop-down box, when I select a value (say Param 1) from the box and click "Submit", I need to print the value (Param 1 in this case). How to achieve this?

Comment: Print the value where?

Comment: Anywhere, say like a paragraph in the same document, I just want to know how to access the selected value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Use the search function :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var s = document.getElementsByName('parameters')[0];
var text = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this work perfectly:**

```
var ex = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var str= ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].value;
 **or**
var str= ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].text;
```

**or**

```
var ex = document.getElementsByName('parameters')[0];
var str= ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].value;
      **or**
var str= ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunc() {
   var par=document.getElementsByName('parameters')[0];
   var index=par.selectedIndex
   console.log(par.options[index].text);
}
```

Comment: This way you get the first element and not the selected one. I think TS meant not the value, but the inner text.

Comment: @Ivil Yes, the innertext of the selected one.